# How to specify multiple files in $sourcePath

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy multiple files locally to network share.

Method I am using

```
$sourcePath = "C:\folder\file.csv"
```

Works fine, but when I add addition file to the same sourcepath it fails, e.g

```
$sourcePath = "C:\folder\file.csv, C:\folder\file2.csv"
```

I would like to be able to copy two separate files specified in sourcepath.

Comment: Please edit the question and include the copy command too.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you consider as "working fine". `$sourcePath = C:\folder\file.csv` should try to open the CSV with the default handler registered for CSV files, not assign the path to the variable. If you want to assign a path string to a variable you need to put the path in quotes. If you want to assign multiple paths to a variable you need to put each path in quotes and separate the strings with commas.

Comment: No I understand that part, i already had quotes but someone had edited it ??

Comment: The quotes you originally had were around the entire expression, which would be wrong in a different way, but still wrong. The quoting you use in the second snippet of your updated question doesn't work b/c it defines a single string with a comma in it. What you need are *two* strings, separated with a comma (`"foo", "bar"`, not `"foo, bar"`).

Answer (score 2):

Per the other answer, just declare your paths as an array of strings by comma separating them. You can then provide them as input to the `-Path` parameter (which accepts an array of strings as input):

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\folder\file.csv','C:\folder\file2.csv' -Destination 'C:\Temp'
```

Or you can provide them via pipeline input, where they are sent to the `-Path` parameter:

```
'C:\folder\file.csv','C:\folder\file2.csv' | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\Temp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `$sourcePath = C:\folder\file.csv, C:\folder\file2.csv` as array in the following way:

```
$sourcePath = "C:\folder\file.csv", "C:\folder\file2.csv"
```

After that you can copy via:

```
$sourcePath | Foreach-Object { Copy-item $_ "C:\temp" -Verbose }
```

Hope that helps.